# Convert this to IntelXDK Cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, intel-xdk

```
   var mytime;
function getPramJs(param) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var parms = query.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<parms.length; i++) {
    var pos = parms [ i ].indexOf('=');
    if (pos > 0) {
    var key = parms [ i ].substring(0,pos).toLowerCase();
    var val = parms [ i ].substring(pos+1);
    if(key == param.toLowerCase())
        return val;
    }
    }
return null;
}
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    var edit ="";
    edit =  getPramJs("edit");
    var chkCounty = getCookie("country");
    var chkCity = getCookie("city");
    if(chkCounty != null){
        $("#country").val(chkCounty);
    }
    if(chkCity != null){
        $("#city").val(chkCity);

    }
    if((chkCounty != null)&&(chkCity != null)){
        $('#firt').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#change').css({'display':'block'});
        if(chkCity=="city 3"){
            $('#content').css({'display':'block'});
        }

        mytime = setInterval(function(){ redirect() }, 1000);
        if(edit=="1"){
            change();
        }
    }else{
        $('#firt').css({'display':'block'});
        $('#change').css({'display':'none'});
    }
 });
   function myStopmytime() {
    clearInterval(mytime);
  }
// Set cookie
function setCookie(name, value, exdays, path, domain, secure) {
    var expires=new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + exdays);
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString()) +
((path == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
((secure == null) ? "" : "; secure");
}

// Read cookie
function getCookie(name){
var cname = name + "=";
var dc = document.cookie;
if (dc.length > 0) {
begin = dc.indexOf(cname);
if (begin != -1) {
begin += cname.length;
end = dc.indexOf(";", begin);
if (end == -1) end = dc.length;
return unescape(dc.substring(begin, end));
}
}
return null;
}

//delete cookie
function eraseCookie (name,path,domain) {
if (getCookie(name)) {
document.cookie = name + "=" +
((path == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
"; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-70 00:00:01 GMT";
}
}
function change(){
        $('#firt').css({'display':'block'});
        $('#change').css({'display':'none'});
         myStopmytime();
}

function showdirec(){
        $('#firt').css({'display':'none'});
        $('#change').css({'display':'block'});
}
function saveLocation(){
    var country =  $( "#country option:selected" ).text() +"";
    if(country != "select your country"){
        eraseCookie("country");
        setCookie("country",country,365);
    }else{

    }
    if(city != "select your city"){
        var city =  $( "#city option:selected" ).text() +"";
        eraseCookie("city");
        setCookie("city",city,365);
    }else{

    }
    redirect();
    //showdirec();
}

function redirect(){
    var lol = "http://pmckw.com";
    var chkCity = getCookie("city");
    if(chkCity =="city 1"){
        lol= "http://pmckw.com";
    }   
    if(chkCity =="city 2"){
        lol= "https://www.google.com/";
    }
    if(chkCity=="city 3"){
        lol= "kuwait.html";

        }
        if(chkCity =="city 4"){
        lol= "kuwait.html";
    }
            redirectTo(lol);
}

function redirectTo(location)
{
     window.location.href =location;
}
```

how do i make this code work with IntelXDK  as intelxdk uses different method to save cookies. please help as i am newbie to intelxdk

below is the link:

https://github.com/01org/cordova-plugin-intel-xdk-cache#removecookie

Comment: Do you have to use cookies, or would local storage be acceptable?

Comment: Also, how many countries and cities will you have, just a few or a great many?

Comment: many countries ......i dont mind cookies or local storage.

Comment: Do you really want to have pages for each possible city? It might be better to have a page that acts as a frame and loads the correct content based on the selected city and country. Do you have a database or other method where you could store that content?

Comment: okay this code is working with browsers but not working with IntelXDK

Comment: @DelightedD0D please help

Comment: You havent answered my questions. Im happy to help but there are many ways that your whole concept can be **greatly** simplified. The route you are taking here is going to lead to a very large amount of **very** repetitive code. Those answers will help me evaluate the direction we should go towards a solution for you

Comment: @DelightedD0D yes i want to have pages for each cities.. please help me with the code whatever u like. I dont mind. I just want it to be able to work with intelxdk cache. Thank you very much.